# Multiple distinct/groupBy in one MongoDB request to get an associative array

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of MongoDB document which look like this:

```
[  
   {  
      "Continent":"Europe",
      "Country":"France",
      "City":"Paris"
   },
   {  
      "Continent":"Europe",
      "Country":"France",
      "City":"Marseille"
   },
   {  
      "Continent":"Europe",
      "Country":"Germany",
      "City":"Berlin"
   },
   {  
      "Continent":"Asia",
      "Country":"China",
      "City":"Beijing"
   }
]
```

And I would like (in a PHP script but whith a Mongo query) to obtain at the end an associative array like this:

```
$cities = array(
            "Europe" => array(
                "France"  => array(
                    "Paris",
                    "Marseille",
                ),
                "Germany" => array(
                    "Berlin",
                ),
            ),
            "Asia"   => array(
                "China" => array(
                    "Beijing",
                ),
            ),
        );
```

I just need to obtain an associative array to be able to display the list of distinct continents; countries and cities, but not in 3 requests because I want to allow the user to filter results so if in the first input the user enter "Europe" I must show only "France" and "Germany" in the country input..

I don't ask anybody for the correct query but I would like a little help to find the correct Mongodb function to use, because I'm very new to Mongo and NoSQL.

Maybe I could use the "aggregate" operator and some "group", or chain multiples "distinct" operator... I don't really know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

Try next approach:

```
function handleCities($json)
{
    $result = [];
    foreach(json_decode($json, true) as $city) {
        $result[$city['Continent']][$city['Country']][] = $city['City'];
    }
    return $result;
}

$cities = '[  
   {  
      "Continent":"Europe",
      "Country":"France",
      "City":"Paris"
   },
   {  
      "Continent":"Europe",
      "Country":"France",
      "City":"Marseille"
   },
   {  
      "Continent":"Europe",
      "Country":"Germany",
      "City":"Berlin"
   },
   {  
      "Continent":"Asia",
      "Country":"China",
      "City":"Beijing"
   }
]';
var_dump(handleCities($cities));
```

Comment: Yes but this is PHP and I would need to iterate over a lot of data. I need to get all of my Document from Mongo and then iterate over them. I thought Mongo could display what I want more more efficiently